# Errors not shown in the js console on ripple debug

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, taco

After a recent update from TACO v8 to TACO v10 and VS 2015 upgrade2 => upgrade3 once a javascript error is triggered in the application I am debuging, it is no longer shown in the Visual Studio javascript console.

What is strange is that I can normally see log messages that are written using console.log. Also when i open then developer console in chrome, I can see that error is there, triggered and recorded.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you get the error message when using an Emulator or a real device?

Comment: Same situation as with ripple unfortunatelly